# Increase a number dependent on value of another?

Tags: jquery

What I need is 'data-cost':

```
<input type="radio" class="selection" data-cost="0" value="One" name="f_1"/>
```

To increase depending on 'value':

```
<input type="number" name="q_1" id="q_1" min="50" value="50" data-quantity="f_1" />
```

So for example, if the customer has between 50-100 items, the cost will be 0.53.
So if `value="50"` I want `data-cost="0.53"`

and if the customer has between 100-200 items, the cost will be 0.44.
So if `value="120"` I want `data-cost="0.44"`.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Any jquery codes you tried so far? I noticed SO is becoming a "I want this..." sort of medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$('input[type="number"]').blur(function(){
   if ( $(this).val() >= 50 && $(this).val() <= 100 ) {
     $('.selection').attr('data-cost', '0.53')
   }
})
```

Comment: This did the job, thank you so much. I didn't even know where to start.